Does enabling Outbox in one NServiceBus endpoint force enabling it in all endpoints?
I'm trying to understand if the Outbox feature of NServiceBus is something we should add into our ecosystem.
It is my understanding that the Outbox has one major usecase: making sure logical interaction with the persistence and transport happens in one "transaction". Naively, the transport (in SendsAtomicWithReceive mode) and persistence enlist two separate transactions due to being two separate infrastructural entities. This makes it so that it's impossible to commit both of these transactions in a way that guarantees their either both do happen, or don't happen. This inconsistency causes the "Zombie record/Ghost message" problem. The Outbox solves this by emulating the transport transaction in the persistence, by storing outgoing messages. So far so good.
Within the message handling context, the messages that are stored in the outbox are then sent into the transport and marked as sent in the outbox. This again has the double transaction problem: what if there is a failure between sending the message and marking it as sent? In my understanding, the outbox solves this by sequencing this in such a way, that the message will just be resent on subsequent retries as reaction on the failure.
This double sending of messages is what then forces the deduplication logic performed by the outbox feature at the start of message handers, I guess.
If my understanding of the design of the Outbox is correct so far, this implies that if I enable outbox in endpoint A, I am subsequently forced to enable outbox in all endpoints that handle messages coming from endpoint A in order to deduplicate the messages that were potentially sent multiple times?

Your understanding is correct.
The official documentation  goes into detail about how the feature works. Any receiving endpoint with the Outbox feature turned on will run de-duplication first. If the feature is turned off, no deduplication will take place. Therefore, the feature should be enabled on all participating endpoints that cannot perform an idempotency check.


If my understanding of the design of the Outbox is correct so far, this implies that if I enable outbox in endpoint A, I am subsequently forced to enable outbox in all endpoints that handle messages coming from endpoint A in order to deduplicate the messages that were potentially sent multiple times?

What Sean Feldman says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78587334/199551
but to add to that, its not only the outbox that can generate duplicates when outbox dispatching (partially) fails. Most brokers behave in an "at least once" or "at most once" delivery model. The same message often can be "more than once" processed in an "at least once".
So yes, enabled outbox on ANY endpoint in an environment that allows for "more than once" processing regardless if the sender uses outbox when that endpoint that cannot perform an idempotency check.
From https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/#important-design-considerations


Because deduplication is done using MessageId, messages sent outside of an NServiceBus message handler (i.e. from a Web API) cannot be deduplicated unless they are sent with the same MessageId.
The outbox is expected to generate duplicate messages from time to time, especially if there is unreliable communication between the endpoint and the message broker.


I've tried to improve our guidance based on this SO post. I would appreciate any feedback on the following change:

https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/pull/6689


We use Azure Service Bus as a transport, which if I understand correctly is an "at least once" model. However, most of our endpoints are interacting with databases through APIs. From what I read here the Outbox can't help deduplicate these kinds of side-effects right? We're fine with making those APIs idempotent. However, we are investigating whether it is worth enabling Outbox for our saga endpoints (which do have direct sql access) and looking at the implications of enabling that feature.

And based on my current understanding, this would force us to enable outbox on other endpoints as well, but without receiving the other benefits of the outbox, because they don't do any direct database access.
